# Custom pair class with the operator[] syntax

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, variant

I have this code

```
template<typename firstType,typename secondType> 
struct bpair{ 
    firstType first;
    secondType second;

    bpair(firstType firstNew,secondType secondNew) {
        first = firstNew;
        second = secondNew;
    }

    variant<firstType,secondType> operator[](size_t index) {
        if(index == 0) {
            return first;
        }
        return second;
    }
};
```

```
bpair<string,int> hey = bpair(string("hi"),34);
cout << get<string>(hey[0]);
```

It is just a custom std::pair. Is there a way to load info from the pair using just the [] operator like this?

```
cout << hey[0];
```

Comment: the question is unclear. You can directly access the public members, you don't have to use `std::get`

Comment: Yeah, just write `hey.first` instead of `hey[0]` and all your problems go away

Comment: I know, but I want to use the [] operator as I said

Comment: So what type should `hey[i]` return?

Comment: As you have _now clarified_, yes. Do you ever want to use `operator[]` with a variable argument, or will it always be the literals `[0]` or `[1]`?

Comment: The type should be the types in the template argument, and for the other question, 0 or 1

Comment: do you understand why `get` returns a `std::variant` ? Just trying to better frame the question, perhaps it is "Why do I need std::variant here?". Because once you understood that, I guess it would be easier for you to tell us what you want to do instead.

Comment: `template <std::size_t I> auto& operator[](std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) { if constexpr {I == 0} { return first; } else { return second; }}`? and with UDL `std::cout << hey[0_c] << " " << hey[1_c];`.

Comment: Um, because `first` and `second` can have different types? I don't think get returns a variant, your question is a little confusing to me

Comment: you posted code that works and does something. To accomplish that it uses `std::variant`. You are asking how to do the same without `std::variant`, but then it needs to be different, hence it is not clear why you want no `std::variant` or what you want instead. Is it something like Jarod42 suggested you are looking for?

Comment: what do you want to write in place of the current `cout << get<string>(hey[0]);` ?

Comment: You could use `std::any operator[](size_t index)`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, and I prefer the `hey[0]` to remain like that

Comment: @Eljay But I'll still need to use any_cast

I think I'll clarify my question up a bit

Comment: frankly, then it seems you don't completely understand why `std::variant` is needed. A function can have only one return type. It cannot return either one or the other type depending on a runtime parameter

Comment: Then how does the standard array classes have the feature? Is there some kind of alternative

Comment: In the `std::array`, all elements have the _same_ type by definition. (It's an essential feature of an array.) In opposition to that, the `std::get` (to be applied e.g. to `std::tuple`) has the index as _template_ parameter (in opposition to `std::array::operator[]()` where it's a function parameter). Thus, `std::get` can "specialize" into multiple overloads with distinct return types.

Comment: This is getting too long, all I want is a yes or no (which is a yes but I'm getting mixed stuff and its slowly turning into a no) and some usable code as an alternative, not people telling me that I don't know about C++ and shouldn't be asking this question (yeah, I do admit, I'm kinda new, but still)

Comment: @Bfyuvf Return type of the function must be known at compile time. If you can provide a compile-time constant for every call to `operator[]`, you can use Jarod's solution and the answer is "yes, it's possible". If you want to support run-time arguments (based on user's input for example), the answer is "no, it's not possible", because it's not a compile-time constant anymore.

Comment: I never said that you shouldn't be asking the question. Rather I was asking for clarification, and indeed it turned out that "use `std::any`" is not the answer you were looking for, but as I suspected an answer rather needs to explain why `std::variant` is needed in the first place. "This is getting too long" indeed. Sometimes it takes some time with comments to find out what the question really is about. I suppose now it is more or less clear and someone could wrap it up in an answer

Comment: "but as I suspected an answer rather needs to explain why std::variant is needed in the first place." If not std::variant (and also not std::any) then how can I return a value when the type varies? It's not possible, but I suppose I should also end this

Comment: @Bfyuvf the return type cannot vary depending on a runtime parameter. You can use `std::variant` or `std::any` to encapsulate values of different types. You can also not use `std::variant` or `std::any` to do similar but then you need to reinvent a wheel. The simple answer is drop the requirement that the function should be called like this `hey[0];`

Answer (score 1):

A function can have only one return type. The return type cannot depend on a runtime parameter passed to the function.

Your `cout << get<string>(hey[0]);` selects at compile time that you want to retrieve the `std::string` member from the `std::variant`.

It is not (easily) possible to make this possible

```
cout << hey[0];
```

When `hey[0]` and `hey[1]` are supposed to call the same function.

You could let `hey` return some proxy type that when piped to `std::cout` selects the right member. Eventually, this would use again `std::variant` or similar under the hood (and require some boilerplate for not much gain).

For a solution that selects the member to be returned at compile time I repeat a solution suggested by Jarod42:

> ```
> template <std::size_t I> 
> auto& operator[](std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) { 
>     if constexpr {I == 0} { return first; }     
>     else { return second; }
> }
>
> std::cout << hey[0_c] << " " << hey[1_c];
> ```

Note that `hey[0_c]` and `hey[1_c]` are calling two different instantiations of the template. Each with a different return type.